# Groupby using Django's ORM to get a dictionary of lists between two models

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by, django-orm

I have two models, `User` and `Gift`:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    ...


class Gift(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "User",
        related_name="users",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ...
```

Now I want to create a dictionary of lists to have a list of *gifts* for every *user*, so that I can lookup pretty fast the `ids` of gifts that some users have, in a for loop, without having to query the database many times. I came up with this:

```py
from itertools import groupby
gifts_grouped = {
    key: [v.id for v in value] for key, value in groupby(gifts, key=lambda v: v.user_id)
}
```

Now every time I wish to lookup the gifts of a user, I can simply do:

```py
gifts_grouped[id_of_a_user]
```

And it'll return a list with ids of gifts for that user. Now this feels like a Python solution to a problem that can easily be solved with Django. But I don't know how. Is it possible to achieve the same results with Django's ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this, you can query with:

```
users = User.objects.prefetch_related('users')
```

For a user you can then:

```
for user in users:
    for gift in user.users.all():
        print(user, ' -> ', gift)
```

The reason you access these through `.users` is because of the [**`related_name=..`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), which also shows why this is not a good name. You can use:

```
from django.conf import settings


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    # …


class Gift(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='gifts',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # …
```

Then you access these with:

```
users = User.objects.prefetch_related('gifts')
for user in users:
    for gift in user.gifts.all():
        print(user, ' -> ', gift)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).